# Network adapters not responding on all computers

Tags: wireless-networking

To avoid outside people from using my network, I have reserved the mac addresses of all computers of my colleagues on 4 different routers. All 4 routers are on the same network and all of them provide DHCP. The DHCPs provide IPs as these,

```
R1● 192.168.1.10-20, 
R2● 192.168.1.21-30, 
R3● 192.168.1.31-40 and 
R4● 192.168.1.41-50
```

192.168.1.1 (Gateway for all 4 routers)
This way any computer whose mac is reserved can connect to any of the 4 routers as they are on the same network. The mac is not repeated here.

Now the problem is that the computer after connecting to the routers cannot connect next time or after sometime when the computer is restarted or the next time when the computer is turned on. The wireless network stays down, the network doesn't respond even the properties box doesn't open. most of the time it stays as it is after several restarts of the computer. Mostly I disable and enable back the wifi from the device manager which even doesn't work sometime. The properties of the wifi is not accessible from anywhere else during this situation.

Does the Mac address reservation causing this problem? This has been a headache since I applied mac reservations. The is no problem for mobile phones which is surprising too. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Is this issue happening only one one computer for multiple?

Comment: it is on all computers.

Comment: Your Mac reservations are not the cause... Why do you have the routers handing out DHCP and do they all hand out the same IP range and have the same SSID? If so, this is probably your problem.

Comment: All routers have different ssid but the same gateway. they provide different ip ranges as I have mentioned before i.e. R1, R2, R3 and R3 are the routers with the IPs.